# Changing Server PHP from 5.6 to 7.2 casuse Timezone Change to UTC

Tags: php, centos, timezone, php-7, whm

I've just noticed that when I set via WHM my PHP version from 5.6 to 7.2, the timezone has changed from EST to UTC.

I don't think the server's timezone has changed, but probably it's just the "PHP" timezone.

Why is it happening? What's the easiest way to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the output of `phpinfo()`, look at the path of `php.ini` file under **Loaded Configuration File** section.

open your `php.ini` file and change the value of `date.timezone` variable to your desired time zone.

Restart your server.